# jQuery see if radio button is checked in a table

Tags: jquery, radio-button

```
$('#tableId').on('change', ':radio', function () {
    console.log($(this));
    console.log($(this).attr('checked'));
});
```

the second console statement prints undefined. I am not sure why, this $(this) looks like it is holding the right input element.

EDIT:

I am trying to do something like this http://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/EtNXP/ but my radio buttons are in a table

```
$('#tableId').on('change', ':radio', function () {
    console.log($(this).is(':checked'));
    var prevValue = $(this).attr('previousValue');
    if(prevValue == "true")
    {
      $(this).attr('checked', false);
    }
    $(this).attr('previousValue', $(this).is(':checked'));
  });
```

Comment: Use jQuery's `.is()` method. Or just put in a `:` before the word checked

Comment: Please post your HTML and if possible, a jsFiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `this.checked` or `$(this).prop('checked')` or `$(this).is(':checked')` instead of using `attr`.

```
$('#tableId').on('change', ':radio', function () {
    console.log($(this));
    console.log(this.checked);
});
```

You want to do this, to make the radio deselectable:

```
 $('#radioinstant').click(function() {
    var previousValue = $(this).data('previousValue');
    this.checked = !previousValue;
    $(this).data('previousValue', this.checked);
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xgNAD/)**

Also do not do this on `change` event (it happens after the change has been done you can no longer change the state of radio from inside the change event), you need to do this on `click` event which happens before change and where you can cancel or change the state of radio button.

change:

```
$('#tableId').on('change', ':radio', function () {
```

to:

```
$('#tableId').on('click', ':radio', function () {
```

Comment: Right, but they are in a table, so how do I do it then. Thats my issue, getting at the element in the table to change the attribute for.

Comment: This should work no matter where it is with appropriate selector. But without showing your markup and clarifying your question it will be difficult to assist.

Comment: See my answer update, YOu need to use click event instead of change event

Comment: I didnt realize the difference between the click and the change. Thanks a lot for the quick responses.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and change the selectors accordingly.

```
$('#tableId').on('click', ':radio', function() {
   if($(this).is(':checked'))
       console.log("Yes");
   else
       console.log("No");
});
```